# Using flex with two 50% divs creates scroll bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use md-dialog with two 50% divs. How can I avoid the scroll bar in the bottom

So far I tried this:
And this is the result[image]

```
<md-dialog id="testTemplate-dialog">
    <div layout="row">
        <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Test1</label>
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.test.Name" ng-required="true" />
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container flex="50">
            <label>Test2</label>
            <input ng-model="$ctrl.test.Description" ng-required="true" />
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</md-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to increase the width of the matdialog: or you can just hide the overflow with css:

```
   #testTemplate-dialog{
     overflow: hidden;
     }
```